# RDLC Report generation takes so much time with large data to display

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, rdlc

i am working with rdlc report on a C# windows application, while retrieving a large set of data (say 10, 000 records) from Sqlite database, it takes more than three minutes for the report to generate and render, i think that is too much of time, i have tried to do a little optimization by indexing all fields in my where clause, yet no improvement, i cant do a stored procedure since Sqlite does not have support for it. Below is my code:

```
private DataSet GetData()
    {

        string select = "SELECT DISTINCT OrganisationId AS OrgId,OrganisationName AS OrgName,TaxIdNumber AS TIN,StaffId,StaffName,Department AS Dept,Position,Month,Year,SUM(NoOfMonthsWorked) AS NMnth," +
                        "SUM(BasicSalary) AS BasicSalary,SUM(TransAllowance) AS Transp,SUM(UtilityAllowance) AS Utility,SUM(HousingAllowance) AS Housing,SUM(LeaveAllowance) AS Leave,SUM(ThirteenthMonthAllowance) AS ThirteenMnth," +
                        "SUM(OvertimeAllowance) AS Overtime,SUM(EntertainmentAllowance) AS EnterMnt,SUM(DomesticAllowance) As Domestic,SUM(EducationAllowance) AS Education,SUM(PersonalAllowance) AS Personal,SUM(OtherAllowances) AS Others," +
                        "SUM(HealthFund) AS NHIS,SUM(HousingFund) AS NHF,SUM(LifeAssurance) AS LA,SUM(Gratuities) AS Gratuities,SUM(Pension) AS Pension,SUM(OtherStatutoryDeductions) AS OtherDeducts," +
                        "SUM(ConsolidatedRelief) AS CRA,SUM(TotalRelief) AS TotalRelief,SUM(TaxableIncome) AS TaxableIncome,SUM(TaxExempts) As TTaxExempt,SUM(GrossIncome) AS GrossIncome,SUM(MonthlyTaxDue) AS TaxPayable " +
                        "FROM IncomeTax WHERE(OrganisationId = @OrganisationId AND Year = @Year) GROUP BY StaffId";
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connstring))
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(select))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 9000000;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrganisationId", DbType.String, 50).Value = txtOrgId.Text.ToUpper();
                    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", DbType.String, 50).Value = cboMonthSearch.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", DbType.String, 50).Value = cboYearSearch.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper();
                    using (DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet1())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "DataTable2");
                        if (dsCustomers.Tables[1].Rows.Count == 0)
                        {
                            reportViewer1.Visible = false;
                            MessageBox.Show("Records not found!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reportViewer1.Visible = true;
                        }
                        return dsCustomers;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Click event:

```
private void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        if (txtOrgId.Text != "")
        {
            if (cboYearSearch.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                DataSet dsCustomers = GetData();
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsCustomers.Tables[1]);
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                // the ReportPath is relative to the page displaying the ReportViewer
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report2.rdlc";
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
                this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(cboYearSearch, "Select Year!");
                cboYearSearch.Focus();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtOrgId, "Enter OrgId!");
            txtOrgId.Focus();
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate if anyone could assist on how to get it display a bit more faster. Thanks

Comment: As the old saying goes - you need to find the slow bits, and take them out. Why do you think it's the data retrieval that's taking a long time, rather than the report generation itself? How long does the query take to run when run on it's own? Add some simple timing code using the stopwatch class and you will be able to see where the problems are.

Comment: Query finished in 0.046 second(s) while running on sqlite query window

Comment: So if the query runs in 1/20th of a second, the database isn't likely to be the problem here. Maybe have a look at [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806(v=sql.105).aspx#Process).